# Stored procedure that will return empty value from SQL Server Date column instead of 1900-01-01

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure to retrieve a date column and display the results in my ASP.NET web form. The results are showing the date column as `1900-01-01` if the data was inserted into the database as an empty value. I need it to display as an empty value.

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT 
     *,
     CASE
        WHEN [DateField] = '1900-01-01' OR [DateField] IS NULL 
           THEN ''
     END AS [DateField]
 FROM 
     Table
 WHERE 
     MemberID = @MemberID
```

The `DateField` column should be returning an empty value, but it's still showing the date 1900-01-01

Comment: Can you provide sample data of the column `[DateField]` as well as it's data type? Plus I notice you are doing `Select *` which will return all the columns from the table, are you sure you aren't viewing the column as it is returned from the `SELECT *` and not the one which you modify via the `CASE` statement?

Comment: The type of the column is 'date' and the date is displayed as 1900-01-01

Comment: Please see the second part of my comment as I added it just recently.

Comment: You were correct, the select * was causing the issue. When I changed it to list out the fields as Lukasz suggested, it is working now. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NULLIF`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., NULLIF([DateField] , '19000101') AS [DateField]
FROM Table_name
WHERE MemberID = @MemberID
```

Answer (score 2):

A `CASE` expression returns a value which has the data type precedence ([Data Type Precendence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) of the  returned values. In your `case` you have 2 datatypes; `DateField` which (I assume) is a `date` and `''`, which is a `varchar(1)`. `date` has a higher data precedence than a `varchar` so `''` is implicitly converted to a `date`. And (you can test this using `SELECT CAST('' AS date);`) therefore the value return is `1900-01-01`.

Rather than using an empty string, I would suggest returning `NULL`. Otherwise you have to convert your `[DateField]` column to a `varchar`; and that is a bad idea. You can easily achieve this by replacing your `CASE` with:

```
NULLIF([DateField],'19000101')
```

Comment: While your answer is a possible solution, I am still unconvinced that this is the root problem. The OP is selecting all columns from the table and then another of the Date in the Case statement, using the same column name for both the select * and the case statement select, so when converting values, who knows which column it is actually pulling values from as they have the same column name.

Comment: @RyanWilson even (however doubtful) the OP *is* looking at the wrong Column my answer is still correct. `''` as a `date` is `1900-01-01`: Try this if you don't believe it: `SELECT CASE [DateCol] WHEN '19000101' THEN '' ELSE [DateCol] END FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'20181228')),(CONVERT(date,'19000101'))) V(DateCol);` This returns the values `2018-12-28` **and** `1900-01-01`, because `''` is implicity converted to a `date`. The problem **will** be occuring on the final column in their dataset, regardless of your belief of if they are looking at the wrong column or not.

Comment: If you notice the comments as well as the accepted answer, I was correct.

Comment: @RyanWilson The accepted answer uses `NULLIF`... (which is exactly the same as my answer here.)

Comment: And they also specified the columns instead of using `SELECT *` which would have produced two columns with the same name.

Comment: Luskasz answer would *still* suffer the problem if it used a `CASE` @RyanWilson. His answer doesn't change how the RDBMS fundamentally works.

Comment: [CASE (Transact-SQL) - Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-types) - *"Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For more information, see Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)."* @RyanWilson

Comment: I don't need your basic SQL article as I already understand it. But thanks anyway

Comment: @RyanWilson That's the documentation... It's not my "basic article". /headdesk. If you "knew" it you would know how data precedence works... Hopefully you have learned about it now at least. if not, I do suggest learning about it; it can explain a lot of behaviour people believe is "odd".

Comment: You still don't get it ./headdesk yourself. And I don't need your sarcasm